# java - largest to smallest sort - largest is out of order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to get this sorting algorithm to sort largest to smallest in an array. Here's what I have:

```
private void sort(int[] data) {
    int min;
    for (int index = 0; index < data.length - 1; index++) {
        min = index;
        for (int scan = index + 1; scan < data.length; scan++) {
            if (data[scan] > data[min]) min = scan;
            swap (data, min, index);
        }
    }
}

private void swap(int[] data, int pos0, int pos1) {
    int temp = data[pos0];
    data[pos0] = data[pos1];
    data[pos1] = temp;
}
```

the output is:

```
3 3 4 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

why is the second largest number out of order?

I keep going through this and I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are closing if statement earlier

```
 if (data[scan] > data[min]) min = scan;
            swap (data, min, index);
```

`swap()` will get invoked regard less of `if` condition

Comment: I was intending for the if statement only to cover
    min = scan;
should it also cover the swap?

Comment: I had meant to swap either way, but I see I need to swap only when the condition is met - cheers!  I'll mark this answer when the 10 minutes passes